# How to integrate admob in unity for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1, admob

I want to add admob in unity for windows phone I am unable to find a plugin for integrating it in unity. There is a SDK but it is for windows phone apps not for unity windows phone. So is there a free plugin or something through which i can add admob for windows phone in unity